# ListPicker Items.Clear

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have the following ListPickers on a Windows Phone 8 project:

```
<toolkit:ListPicker Name="Continentes" ExpansionMode="ExpansionAllowed" Grid.Row="1" Width="220" Margin="20,20,261,14" Background="White" Foreground="Black" SelectionChanged="Continentes_SelectionChanged" Canvas.ZIndex="10">
</toolkit:ListPicker>

<Image Source="/Assets/Images/arrow@2x.png" Width="16.5" Height="10.5" Margin="187,49,276,567" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.ZIndex="10" />

<toolkit:ListPicker Name="Paises"  Grid.Row="1" Width="220" Margin="249,20,20,20" Background="White" Foreground="Black" Canvas.ZIndex="10">
</toolkit:ListPicker>
```

The first `ListPicker` is getting populated by a List of strings and it then shows a list of continents:

```
Europe,
Asia,
India...
```

When I select one of the continents, the second picker gets populated by a List of strings containing countries, using the following function, that gets activated on the first picker using the `SelectionChanged` event handler:

```
private void Continentes_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (sender as ListPicker).SelectedItem;
    int selindex = Continentes.SelectedIndex;
    List<string> listaDePaises = new List<string>();

    if (selindex != -1)
    {
        if ((string)selectedItem == "Europa")
        {
            Paises.Items.Clear();
            listaDePaises = countrys.getPaisesByName("Europa");
            Paises.ItemsSource = listaDePaises;
        }

        if ((string)selectedItem == "Asia")
        {
            Paises.Items.Clear();
            listaDePaises = countrys.getPaisesByName("Asia");
            Paises.ItemsSource = listaDePaises;
        }
    }
}
```

The first time I do the `continente selection`, the second picker gets populated, but the second time I tried it, I got the following exception, on the `Items.Clear()` method.

> ```
> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Operation not supported on read-only collection.
> ```

Any idea about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ItemsSource of listpicker binded with a dataSource, the Items is already a read-only collection. You can do like this: Paises.ItemsSource = null; but not:Items.Clear(). I hope it can help you.